# How to search in array of std object (array of object) using in_array php function?

Tags: php, arrayobject

I have following std Object array

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 545
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 548
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 550
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 552
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 554
        )

)
```

I want to search for value of `[id]` key using loop. I have following condition to check whether value is exist or not like below

```
$flag = 1;
if(!in_array($value->id, ???)) {
    $flag = 0;
}
```

Where `???` I want to search in array of std Object's `[id]` key.

Can any one help me for this?

Comment: @Phil, I checked a link which you have specified but I think solution which Jack has provided is far better.

Comment: It depends on the use-case, really. My answer requires more memory, for instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the array isn't too big or the test needs to be performed multiple times, you can map the properties in your array:

```
$ids = array_map(function($item) {
    return $item->id;
}, $array);
```

And then:

```
if (!in_array($value->id, $ids)) { ... }
```

Comment: That's great friend (y). I was looking for this since long time. Again thank you so much.

Comment: As I am able to accept your answer I will accept it and mark as solved.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
foreach ($array as $val) {
 if (!in_array($id, (array) $val)) {
 ...
 }
}
```

Comment: this answer is already given by another user.

Comment: hey this looks familiar..

Answer (score 0):

Why not just cast the objects as arrays:

```
foreach ($array as $a) {
     if (!in_array($id, (array) $a)) {
     ...
     }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why people hate the easy ways ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array is names `$yourArray` ,

```
$newArr = array();
foreach ($yourArray as $key=>$value) {
    $newArr[] = $value->id;
}
```

And now `$newArr` is like : `array(545,548,550,552,554)`

**AND** you can search in it by :

```
$valueOfSearch = ... ;
$flag = 1;
if(!in_array($valueOfSearch,$newArr)) {
    $flag = 0;
}
```