# Search in array, like select?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, php-7

My array with countries is:

```
$cars = array(
    ['brand' => 'bmw', 'place_1' => 'Munich', 'place_2' => 'Cologne'],
    ['brand' => 'vw', 'place_1' => 'Berlin', 'place_2' => 'Kopenhagen'],
    ['brand' => 'hyndai', 'place_1' => 'Miami', 'place_2' => 'Newyork'],
);
```

I can select a name with this command: $cars[1]['place_2'] the nr. 1 is position in array, but I need it by "brand" because this values are dynamic.

I need something like this: `$cars['brand' => 'bmw']['place_2']` or `$cars->brand['bmw']['place2']`, but the syntax is incorrect.

How can I get name by code for example *place2* from *brand* bmw, I think my array is correct and I need only true select?

My previous sources are:

[PHP - find entry by object property from a array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742903/php-find-entry-by-object-property-from-a-array-of-objects)

[How to search in array of std object (array of object) using in_array php function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21275014/how-to-search-in-array-of-std-object-array-of-object-using-in-array-php-functi?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Reference PHP array by multiple indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405281/reference-php-array-by-multiple-indexes?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Some of this examples works, but no one is like select, is it possible in a array?

Comment: You can use **foreach** loop and write a custom function.

Comment: Exactly as I have answered already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your brands as array keys instead of using numeric array indexes.

Something like this

```
$cars = [
  'bmw' => ['place_1' => 'Munich', 'place_2' => 'Cologne'],
  'vw' => ['brand' => 'vw', 'place_1' => 'Berlin', 'place_2' => 'Kopenhagen'],
  'hyndai' => ['brand' => 'hyndai', 'place_1' => 'Miami', 'place_2' => 'Newyork'],
];
```

Then you can access the variables like you want to: `$cars['bmw']['place_1']`

---

P.S : "hyndai" is probably a typo - it's spelled **Hyundai**

Comment: That was my first thought but this changes the data structure - so not exact to the original question

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but something like this

```
   function arraySelect($arr,$brand){
        $selection=[];
        foreach($arr as $a){
                if($a["brand"]=$brand{
                        array_push($selection,$a);
                }
        }
        return $selection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have opportunity to rebuild your array as @Daniel suggested, then you have to iterate over it, something like this:

```
$brand_to_find = 'bmw';
$key_to_select = 'place_2';

foreach ($cars as $car) {
    if ($car['brand'] == $brand_to_find) {
        echo $car[$key_to_select];

        // if you're sure that will be no
        // more `bmw` in your array - break
        break;
    }
}
```

All wrapped in a function:

```
function findPlaceByBrand($cars, $brand_to_find, $key_to_select) 
{
    $result = '';

    foreach ($cars as $car) {
        if ($car['brand'] == $brand_to_find) {
            $result = $car[$key_to_select];

            // if you're sure that will be no
            // more `bmw` in your array - break
            break;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

echo findPlaceByBrand($cars, 'bmw', 'place_2');   // Cologne
echo findPlaceByBrand($cars, 'vw', 'place_1');    // Berlin
echo findPlaceByBrand($cars, 'honda', 'place_1'); // empty string
```